# browsing spotify with headless chrome shows "enable player in your browser"

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, spotify

## what I want to archive

I am trying to play spotify in background without showing the player.

## env

```sh
$ uname -a
Darwin mbp.local 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Thu Jun 21 20:07:39 PDT 2018; root:xnu-3789.73.14~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

$ chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 2.41.578706 (5f725d1b4f0a4acbf5259df887244095596231db)

$ /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --version
Google Chrome 69.0.3497.81
```

1. normal chromedriver shows and plays spotify without a problem
2. headless chromedriver won't

[image]

```rb
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
  options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/path/to/profile/dir")
  options.add_argument("--headless")
  options.add_argument("--window-size=1280,800")
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
    browser: :chrome,
    options: options,
  )
end

session = Capybara::Session.new(:chrome)
session.visit "https://spotify.com"
# .. login script / login with the same chrome profile without --headless beforehand
session.click_on "Web Player"
# this give me the image above "enable player in your browser"
session.save_screenshot("/path/to/a/filename.png")
```

## my thoughts

1. It's "Widevine Content Decryption Module" related, and widevine doesn't load-up in headless no matter what?
2. If on a headless linux with xvfb + normal chromedriver will play spotify?

Comment: Idk about 1, but about 2: Yeah, spotify works with this solution